# CakePHP Shell Cron email error

Tags: email, shell, cakephp, cron

I am using CakePHP 1.3 and I was able to successfully able setup the cron job to run shells using the example that was given in the [CakePHP Book.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1110/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs)

```
*/5 *   *   *   * /full/path/to/cakeshell myshell myparam -cli /usr/bin -console /cakes/1.2.x.x/cake/console -app /full/path/to/app >> /path/to/log/file.log
```

This outputs the results into a log file but I want to receive email when there is an error so I can try to resolve the problem.
I tried the following with no luck.

1. If I remove the >> /path/to/log/file.log then even the successful run is emailed.
2. > /dev/null, my assumption was it would send a successful to /dev/null and error to email.
3. 1> /dev/null, tried another variation of 2

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huseyin,

This is not a CakePHP error then, and is maybe a question better suited for serverfault, as you would script your solution.

Bash's built-in facilities are up to the task, try [The linux documentation project's](http://tldp.org) neat introductory tutorials on shell scripting and `#man bash`.

Your solution basically has to use a temporary file or variable in which you store the output of the last cron job run. If there is an error:

`cat THE_TMP_FILE | mail -s "Error from Server Huseyin's server" huseyin@fancy_domain.com`

else:
  `cat THE_TMP_FILE >> blah.blah.log`

Unfortunatly, you need a MTA available, in order to make the `mail` command. If you do not have access to the `mail` command, then you set another cron job following the first in time which then simply runs a `if [ -e THE_FILE_CONTAINING_THE_LAST_ERROR]; then { echo $(cat  THE_FILE_CONTAINING_THE_LAST_ERROR); rm -v THE_FILE... ;} ; fi`

Of course this is not working code, but pretty close, so you'll get the idea.

Comment: It seems like CakePHP will output something whenever you try to use the shell so there is no easy way to only get failed emails.